# Getting start and end date from date range picker

Tags: php, mysql

I am using this date range picker : http://www.daterangepicker.com/
This is his code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon">
            <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" id="reservation">
    </div>
</div>
```

And I'm using simple button to submit form:

```
<input type="button" name="reservation-submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit!">
```

How can I get start and end date from date range picker to two strings after i post form?

EDIT:
Just browse through comments of post highlighted as answer!

Comment: counter question: why did you tag as php and mysql with no code to support the question?

Comment: but what code should I put? I know that it needs to be in form and it is..only thing i need is how to get start and end date in my db.php in which I insert those and some other strings in mysql database

Comment: you set up appropriate form fields for the datepicker to fill in, and then you handle them like any OTHER form field once the form's submitted to the server.

Comment: but I need separate strings..e.g $startdate and $enddate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a name to your input and after post, dump `$_POST['yourName']` and see what you get.

Comment: how do we know if they're not using a GET method?

Comment: text input I mean.

Comment: Do you know html form? you have to put your inputs inside a form

Comment: *lol*, yes, I know forms quite well. I've been dealing with them before the Internet was even in your city ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- I was not talking to you. you are right about form being GET or POST.

Comment: you are wrong about internet in my city tough!

Comment: If you were born after 1990 or 2000, well, there you go *lol* - Forms have been around even before the 90's.

Comment: It is inside form..I know that..I'll try this with giving name to input and dumping it..

Comment: you where talking about internet in my city not my birthday big head, lol

Comment: @NevenGrguric what is you dump result?

Comment: @eeXBee string(23) "08/17/2016 - 08/20/2016"

Comment: then: $outputArray = explode('-', $postedInput);

Comment: so I should make var_dump of $_POST a string e.g $dates and then $outArray = explode('-', $dates)?

Comment: you dont need a var_dump. var_dump was just for debug. You just need to explode posted data and do whatever you want with it.

Comment: That worked..thank you!